# How can we profit from the concept of neighborhood?

Tags: general-topology

Always, when working on Topology and taking a neighborhood of a point $x$, we end up using an open set $G$ that contains $x$. Why, then, mathematicians define the concept of neighborhood if always we end up working with open sets? How can we exploit that generality?

Comment: Not always. I have seen the term "compact neighbourhood" used, for instance (though I can't remember where...). It's just that so much of the machinery of topology relates to open sets, which makes them easy to focus on.

Comment: A neighborhood of $x$ is by definition an open set containing $x$. What do you think of when you hear open set versus neighborhood?

Comment: @AOrtiz No, the most common definition of neighbourhood does not require the set to be open, just to contain an open set containing $x$.  See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics))

Comment: I ' ve noticed the same and think  for the most part it's a useless historical hangover from when  topology was being developed.  I suggest you have a look at neighborhood spaces.  Of additional interest may be networks.

Comment: @WilliamElliot It allows for formulations like: a space is locally compact iff every point has a compact neighbourhood (or a local base of compact neighbourhoods, if you fancy a stronger version, equivalent in Hausdorff spaces). Or space is $T_3$ iff every point has a local base of closed neighbourhoods.